# How to output an entire loop in easygui python

Tags: python, loops, easygui

I am trying to output a string of charaters from one loop into an easygui.msgbox.

I tried running this code:

```
import easygui

n = 9

for i in range (9):
    if i == n:
        easygui.msgbox(str(i))
    else:
        easygui.msgbox(str(i)+",",)
```

But multiple windows open with one one cycle of the loop. And when i press okay the next number appears.

```
0,
```

But my desired results are this in one mesagebox.

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: Use another variable to store full string first, then after that, use msgbox to showing the result (after for combining string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call easygui.msgbox, it will open a message box.
You're calling it 9 times in a loop.
You want to just call it once, but with your complete string

```
import easygui

msg = ','.join(str(i) for i in range(9))
easygui.msgbox(msg)
```

if it's easier to understand, you can build up your string separately first like you did (but don't call `easygui.msgbox` until you have built up the entire string you want to display).

- Also, since `range(9)` goes from 0-8, your `if i == n:` won't do anything since n==9.
- Also, if you're going to assign `n=9` at the start, you probably want to use that variable in your loop as well `for i in range(n):`